# Catch and don't report one particular exception

Tags: android, crashlytics

In my android app I use crashlytics to collect crash reports. I have noticed that I have many crashes caused by [DeadSystemException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadSystemException) what is not my fault so I would like not to collect them.

Is there any way to catch all DeadSystemExceptions globally (in my Application class) to avoid reporting them to crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the issue and then mute/lock them so that the issue is not regressed when the same crash comes in for other build versions. Screenshots attached for reference.[image: For Fabric]

[image: For firebase]

Comment: It's not a good solution because that exception takes place in many different places so I would need to mute many issues.

Comment: Does this also remove the particular crash from the numbers?